# Pattern to store temporary values with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

#### The Pattern

I keep finding myself doing this and I'm not sure if it's fine, or if I'm approaching things the wrong way.

Consider the following:

```js
const unfoldLast = curry(
  (pred, fn, init) => pipe(
    unfold(n => 
      (next => pred(n, next) && [n, next])(fn(n))
    ),
    last
  )(init)
);
```

Specifically,

`n => (next => pred(n, next) && [n, next])(fn(n))`

doesn't read well to me. It's an anonymous function that uses its closure and is invoked immediately.

I'd rather it look like this:

`n => pred(n, fn(n)) && [n, fn(n)]`

This behaves the exact same, only it runs fn(n) twice.

#### The problem

I find myself employing this pattern of an immediately invoked anonymous function as a way to `store` a temporary value relatively often. I'm not sure how to do something similar in a way that's easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any great way around this.  I find I switch between what you're doing and the use of `call` depending on my current needs.

```js
n => (next => pred(n, next) && [n, next])(fn(n))
```

can be rewritten as

```js
n => call (
  (next) => pred (n, next) && [n, next],
  fn (n)
)
```

or equivalently as

```js
n => call (
  (next = fn (n)) => pred (n, next) && [n, next]
)
```

Sometimes when I'm not using Ramda<sup>1</sup>, instead of defining `call` as `(fn, ...args) => fn (...args)`, I will use this version: `(fn) => {with: (...args) => fn (...args)}` which I can then use as `call (myFunction) .with ('some' , 'args')`.  But that's really only helpful when working with a named function.

I'm a big fan of expression-only coding, using no statements in my function definitions, only expressions.  That is what leads to this problem.  If you don't mind including some statements, this can also be written as

```js
n => {
  const next = fn(n)
  return pred (n, next) && [n, next]
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.

Comment: `call((next = fn(n)) =>` is super weird, but I can easily see how it works and that the contained function is immediately called; So I do think it looks better. I'm wondering if just using statements in this situation is clearest, but I'll stick with expressions as that's the point for now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the correct answer above, you could also make it more readable by extracting some bits (and gain some utilities for free):

```
const tupleWith = curry((fn, x) => [x, fn(x)]);
```

Your unfold iterator function would then look like:

```
pipe(tupleWith(fn), unless(pred, F))
```

If you can't change the shape of `pred` to accept an array, you can always wrap it with `apply(pred)`.